# When I double-click flutter_console.bat, It is opening and closing itself in one second?

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRnxR.jpg)I just only downloaded "git" and flutter windows stable zip. I set up zip on the one file of in my C: drive and when I tried to run flutter_console.bat, It is opening and closing in one second. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try executing it from a shell then you might get more information.

Comment: How can I exucute from shell?

Comment: Open a command line and enter the path of the file you want to execute and press enter. If it was added to the `PATH` environment variable just `flutter_console.bat` should do.

Comment: can you share the screen pic ?

Comment: Here: https://i.hizliresim.com/YQV3OE.jpg

Comment: the picture link is showing forbidden error, can you add it to your question ?

Comment: What Windows version are you using?

Comment: imgur.com is fobidden in my country, but I added picture, can you see?

Comment: I use Windows 10 Home Single Language

Comment: Ensure `C:\Windows\System32` is in your `PATH` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I added `C:\Windows\System32` in System Variables with named `PATH`, I fixed this problem. Thanks for solution to @Günter Zöchbauer